# How do I implement custom authentication/authorization for event consumption with SQS?

Tags: authentication, authorization, amazon-sqs, event-sourcing

I'm setting up an event sourcing mechanism using SNS-SQS. I'm planning to use SNS as the topic subscription and consuming events using SQS. 
My use-case is to allow/deny event consumption based on event types. Is there a clean way to do this?

I'm thinking of setting up an API gateway as a proxy through which SQS would be consumed and adding authorization through this API gateway, as defined in this document - https://dzone.com/articles/creating-aws-service-proxy-for-amazon-sqs.

However, I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think SQS/SNS is a good choice here - what will you do with an event after you "deny" it (it must be read from SQS to know the content)?  Spend time clarifying your model & interactions, then choose the right technology to support it afterwards

Comment: I agree with @Krease. Messaging is used to deliver messages from A to B. Messages are per definition a medium, their life cycle ends at consumption. Event-sourcing by definition is using events as the source of truth and keeping them forever.